# Is there a way to get IntelliJ to show me the actual lines in my file where an error occurred in the stack trace?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I'm kind of new to this IDE and am currently trying to find a bug in my Java Spring program. However, the stack trace only gives me this in terms of line number:

```
 UserAlertService.java from InputFileObject:674
```

Is there a way for me to get the real line number instead of that InputFileObject value?

Comment: It looks like the code was obfuscated/protected. Do you have the source code for this class? How do you build it? It it possible to disable obfuscation/enable debug info when compiling?

Comment: That's kind of what I was wondering... I'm just using the native IntelliJ build button but I don't know how to make it not obfuscate the code. I don't think I should share the source code online.

Comment: Is that a Gradle/Maven project? Are there any custom build steps that would hide debug info or adjust the bytecode generation options?

Comment: To my knowledge, no to both of those questions. We don't use Maven or Gradle for building and our build process only involves the native IntelliJ build tool.

Comment: The issue is not clear, please contact support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Do you enable auto build switch such as below? path:File--Settings--Compiler
[image: build-automatically]